# Error while creating custom queries in spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

I am new to spring boot and I am facing the below error when adding queries to my code,

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'testController': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'testService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'testService': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Validation failed for query for method public abstract rest.Test
>   rest.services.TestService.findByXY(java.lang.String)!

below are my code files,

**Test.java**

```
@Entity
public class Test {
@Id
private int id;
@Column
private String x;
@Column
private String y;

public Test() {

}

public Test(int id, String x, String y) {
    this.id = id;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
}
```

**TestService.java**

```
public interface TestService extends CrudRepository<Test, Integer> {
@Query("select id, x, y from test where x = :x")
Employee findByXY(@Param("x") String x);
}
```

**TestController.java**

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

@Autowired
private TestService testService;

@GetMapping("/get-x")
public Employee findX() {
    //System.out.println(testService.findByXY("123"));
    return testService.findByXY("123");
}
}
```

PS: I am following this tutorial page - [link to tutorial](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-introduction-to-query-methods/)

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: annotate your `TestService.java` interface with `@Service` and let me know the status.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna I got the same error..

Comment: Try to pass nativeQuery `true` like `@Query("select id, x, y from test where x = :x", nativeQuery = true)`

Comment: @hrdkisback it worked !! but why did it fail for the previous one ?

Comment: @Arigato Manga without `nativeQuery` flag you have to write HQL query not native so if you want to write native query you have to set `nativeQuery` flag `true`.

Comment: @hrdkisback thanks..if possible can you answer the question so that i will move it to accepted answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have write `native` query so, Try to pass nativeQuery true like

`@Query("select id, x, y from test where x = :x", nativeQuery = true)`

Or you can write `HQL` query

`@Query("SELECT t.id, t.x, t.y FROM Test t where t.x = :x")`

Please refer this link for more info. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Comment: Note that `@Query("select id, x, y from Test where x = :x")` is not a valid HQL or JPQL syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear :

> Validation failed for query for method public abstract rest.Test
>   rest.services.TestService.findByXY(java.lang.String)!

The syntax is not correct for a JPQL query :

```
 @Query("select id, x, y from test where x = :x")
 Employee findByXY(@Param("x") String x);
```

Select rather a `Test` and returns also a type that matches to your query :

```
 @Query("select t from Test t where t.x = :x")
 Test findByXY(@Param("x") String x);
```

Otherwise, specify a native query if you want to do that as  hrdkisback suggested, by adding `nativeQuery = true`.

Comment: the code i posted is a blueprint of my actual code, so the actual code is for employee and i posted it as test..in the question i changed employee to test but I forgot to change the return type for that function..

Comment: @Arigato Manga All right. Anyway, the syntax is not correct. You have to select the entity, not the fields of it.

Comment: @YCF_L you are a saviour !! I was modifying my code for the same purpose. Your answer saved a lot of time..really thanks..(your answer for fetching the data..wonder why you deleted it)
if possible can you tell me in how many other ways can i do the same thing..(a link to a tutorial or link to SO question would also help, only if possible)...
but really thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

This query :

```
select id, x, y from test where x = :x
```

return 3 parameters `id`, `x`, and `y` and not an object of type `Employee`

So the return type should be `List<Object[]>` and not `Employee`

```
@Query("select id, x, y from test where x = :x")
List<Object[]> findByXY(@Param("x") String x);
```

---

Then you can iterate through this list like this :

```
List<Object[]> listTest = findByXY(x);
List<Test> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Object[] test : listTest) {
    resultList.add(
            new Test((Integer) test[0],
                    (String) test[1],
                    (String) test[2])
    );
}
```